# Why the selenium work only sometimes when I am trying to download pdf?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the download of pdf files from the site. I have saved all the pdf links in a list and i am iterating over that list and trying to download a pdf file into a specified download path, but it is working for few urls and not working for others. And surprisingly if I stop and rerun the program it downloads the pdfs which was not working in previous try. And its totally random, there's no pattern whatsoever and

Please help me. Thanks

Pasting my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


def download_pdf(file_name, url, download_path):
    try:
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

        prefs = {
            "download.default_directory": download_path,
            'download.prompt_for_download': False,
            'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': True
        }

        options.add_experimental_option('prefs',prefs)

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get(url)
        # Wait for some time to ensure the PDF is loaded
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        #Find the DOWNLOAD Button from the pdfviewer using the id of button tag
        download_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "download")
        time.sleep(3)
        download_button.click()
        time.sleep(6)

    except Exception as e:
        print("EXCEPTION ",e)
```

I tried almost all the solutions on the internet possible.

1. My chromedriver path is set in environment variable
2. Chromedriver version and chrome are both compatible.
3. I am not writing any print lines and giving enough delays to load the file

Comment: I'd recommend you to use WebDriverWait to wait for the 'download' button to be clickable, instead of using the fixed sleeps, and also, wait for the file to be created in the target dir (len(os.listdir(download_path))). Take the number of files before the download, and wait for the +1 file after clicking the button. It also makes sense to wait for the exact extension (.pdf) of the last modified file in the download dir.